# Restrict interface to specific classes or restrict a property/declare to specific class+interface

Tags: inheritance, interface, strict

I have an Interface IDataControl:

```
public interface IDataControl
{
    ...
}
```

Then, I have a class with a variable of List<IDataControl>.

```
List<IDataControl> items;
```

The problem is when I try to add elements of this collection in a "Controls" property of another form or another control:

```
panel.Controls.Add(items[i]);
```

The IDE says me that "The best overloaded method matching......" because "IDataControl" is not inherited from "Control".

I understand the error, and I kwnow that I can do some casting like:

```
panel.Controls.Add(   (Control)items[i]   );
```

But, I want to know if there is a "cleaner" way to do this, without requiring a casting, having also strict type verifying.



So, is it possible to indicate that "IDataControl" only can be implemented by Control derived objects?

```
public interface IDataControl where this : Control
{
    ...
}
```

Or, is it possible to declare a variable of a class and a interface?
Something like this:

```
Control:IDataControl item;
List<Control:IDataControl> items;
```

Thanks

Comment: any success with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you already understood System.Windows.Forms.Control does know nothing about your interface.

---

```
public interface IDataControl where this : Control
{
    ...
}
```

You can't do that. It is Applied for [generics type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) 
Also interfaces can not be inherited from class.
An interface has the following properties:

- An interface is like an abstract base class: any non-abstract type
  that implements the interface must implement all its members.
- An interface cannot be instantiated directly.
- Interfaces can contain events, indexers, methods, and properties.
- Interfaces contain no implementation of methods.
- Classes and structs can implement more than one interface.
- An interface itself can inherit from multiple interfaces.

What you need is perhaps next:
When you create you controls, inherit them from your interface.

In this host control you need to create a method

```
private void AddDataControl(IDataControl dataControl)
{
   if(IDataControl is Control){
      //your logic
   }
   else{
      throw new ArgumentException();
   }
}
```

It's just general approach. Depends on your code.